# Filling multiple html fields with a single DB access

Tags: php, html, ajax, wordpress

It's a long question but not too complicated so please bear with me.

I'm building a WordPress site.
One of the pages is supposed to show a list of shops.
There are 5 fields which I'm supposed to populate with shops I'm getting from the DB.

For now I'm doing it like this (in the page templates):

There's a javascript ajax request that works once the html is loaded and that asks for the PHP code on the server's side to get the shops from the DB.
When they're returned, the javascript then populates the html fields with those shops.

Now, I know this is wrong performance wise.
I should populate the fields on the server side before the html is sent to the client.

So my question is this:
There's no sense in accessing the DB 5 times (for the 5 shops and fields).
I just want to access it once, get all the 5 shops, and populate the fields.
But how do I use the returned array from the DB in 5 different places in the html?

In this example I'm getting all the shops into one field. How do I pass them to the rest of the fields?

```
<tr><td><input id="shop1" type="textbox" value="<?php global $wpdb; echo $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM shops"); ?>"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input id="shop2" type="textbox" value=""></td></tr>
<tr><td><input id="shop3" type="textbox" value=""></td></tr>
<tr><td><input id="shop4" type="textbox" value=""></td></tr>
<tr><td><input id="shop5" type="textbox" value=""></td></tr>
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure whether i got the problem: In your example the 5 shops are next to each other, so you could use a simple loop. Is this a real world example? I. e. are the 5 shops are always next to each other?

Comment: Well, this is a very simplified example. In some parts of my code they are next to each other so I guess I can use a loop but in some they're not. So I'm looking for a way to pass the data between non adjacent fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case there is no HTML between shops:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM shops");
?>

//stuff

<?php foreach( $results as $result ): ?>
<tr><td><input id="shop<?php echo $result -> shop_id; ?>" type="textbox" value="<?php echo $result -> fieldName; ?>"></td></tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

And if there is, something like this:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM shops");
?>

<tr><td><input id="shop1" type="textbox" value="<?php echo $results[0] -> fieldName; ?>"></td></tr>

//random stuff here

<tr><td><input id="shop2" type="textbox" value="<?php echo $results[1] -> fieldName; ?>"></td></tr>

//random stuff here

<tr><td><input id="shop3" type="textbox" value="<?php echo $results[2] -> fieldName; ?>"></td></tr>

//random stuff here

<tr><td><input id="shop4" type="textbox" value="<?php echo $results[3] -> fieldName; ?>"></td></tr>

//random stuff here

<tr><td><input id="shop5" type="textbox" value="<?php echo $results[4] -> fieldName; ?>"></td></tr>
```

Comment: So the PHP code know about a variable in a different code section, as if the two code parts were consecutive (referring to your first suggestion)?

Comment: I changed the suggestion order as I realized the shops probably come right after each other. Yes, they know about the variables unless something explicitly removes the variables inbetween. Note that I'm just guessing the mysql result structure here.. modify as needed.

Comment: Actually, I need both cases. Great job!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<?php 
global $wpdb; 
$results =  $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM shops");
$i = 1;    
foreach ( $results as $shop ) 
{
  echo '<tr><td><input id="shop'.$i.
       '" type="textbox" value="">'.$shop->name_of_field_you_need.'</td></tr>';
      $i++;
}
?>
```

Comment: So, I'm breaking out of HTML code (which should be before your code) and writing PHP code (your code) which creates some more HTML code and then I'm breaking out of the PHP code to continue with the HTML (should be after your code)?

Comment: This answers part of what I need but that part is written great so thanks and +1.